# How to merge two Office Add-in?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-office, office-addins

I want to merge both types of Office Add-Ins (Task Pane add-in and Content add-in) into one add-in project. Content add-in should be open from Task Pane add-in. Is it possible? And how to merge them?

I work in Visual Studio 2015 with PowerPoint Web Add-in.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is something that Elio Struyf wrote an blogpost on a while ago, you can find it [here](http://www.eliostruyf.com/combining-multiple-office-apps-into-one-global-app/). In short they just reference the same website and use a query string to identify the right client.

Hope this helps,
Jesse